# Setting attributes of an object that was created in a function

Tags: r, attributes, environment, scoping

(The title is probably quite bad, but I'm not sure how to describe it better)

I have a (rich) object that is created via a function. This object has multiple attributes. One attribute is a function, that should (among other things) change the value of another attribute.

Here is a minimal example of what I want to do:

```
rich_object <- list(1,2,3)


attr(rich_object, "subset_function") <- function(i){
  attr(rich_object, "value_to_change") <<- attr(rich_object, "value_to_change")[1:i]

}

attr(rich_object, "value_to_change") <- 1:20


attr(rich_object, "value_to_change")

attr(rich_object, "subset_function")(10)

attr(rich_object, "value_to_change")
```

This works exactly the way I want it to work. (except that I have to use the evil `<<-` operator)

When I use the same code and wrap it in a function to generate the object it doesn't work anymore.

```
create_awesome_object <- function(a,b,c){

  awesome_object <- list(a,b,c)

  value_to_change <- 1:20

  attr(awesome_object, "subset_function") <- function(i){
    attr(awesome_object, "value_to_change") <<- attr(awesome_object, "value_to_change")[1:i]

  }

  attr(awesome_object, "value_to_change") <- value_to_change

  awesome_object

}



rich_object_2 <- create_awesome_object(1,2,3)

attr(rich_object_2, "value_to_change")
attr(rich_object_2, "subset_function")(10)
attr(rich_object_2, "value_to_change")
```

Would be awesome if somebody could point me to a solution (even better if it would work without `<<-`)

EDIT: I know that that there are better ways to do stuff like that. But I have to work with pre-existing code and refactoring the whole project is currently not possible.

Comment: You probably want to create a `class`. Here's a tutorial: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/OO-essentials.html (link seems down now, but I'm sure it'll come back... also mirrored on archive.org)

Comment: @Frank: I know that this should not be done like this. Unfortunately this is part of a larger package and because of backwards compatibility I have to stick with these strange attribute functions....

Comment: @ja-thomas Really, you should stop shaving this yak (attribute functions) and start shaving the refactoring yak. Should not be longer and it will be less error-prone.

Comment: @Tensibai Refactoring the whole project is currently not possible (at least not in the near future). So in the meantime I need a solution for the current problem

Comment: @ja-thomas I was just giving my opinion, if it takes you a whole month to workaround this issue and another for the next one, and a whole month to refactor an a few days for the next issue due to clean refactor, it worth it. Refactoring is always possible and should never be wiped out without a clear estimation of the cost of not doing it. (still my opinion,  I've no idea how this could even work with lazy evaluation and the scope switching so it sounds a dead end for me)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I just got pointed to a working solution (there was already something similiar in the project).

The idea is to set the attribute `value_to_change` as a function that returns the value from the parent environment.

Adding the solution for consistency.

```
create_awesome_object <- function(a,b,c){

  awesome_object <- list(a,b,c)

  value_to_change <- 1:20

  attr(awesome_object, "subset_function") <- function(i){
    value_to_change <<- attr(awesome_object, "value_to_change")()[1:i]

  }

  attr(awesome_object, "value_to_change") <- function() value_to_change

  awesome_object

}



rich_object_2 <- create_awesome_object(1,2,3)

attr(rich_object_2, "value_to_change")()
attr(rich_object_2, "subset_function")(10)
attr(rich_object_2, "value_to_change")()
```

Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is some misunderstanding about what `<<-` does (hence all of its evil qualities).

`<<-` assigns in the parent environment. That means if you are in one function, it assigns in the Global environment. But if you are in a function that is in a function, it moves up only one environment, which would be the environment of the first function.

As such, if you are really committed to this form (I personally would try to avoid it), you could switch to the `assign` function. This allows you to declare in which environment you would like to make the assignment. Thus, you could set your function to assign to the Global environment (via `envir = .GlobalEnv`), so it would always assign to the Global environment, regardless of how nested your function is.

Comment: It also depends on if and where the object is already assigned.

Comment: The problem being this line `attr(awesome_object, "value_to_change") <<-` awesome_object is not a reference to the "instance", so assigning to it globally with assign won't help getting the value updated in `rich_object_2` anyway.